# Verifying Modular exponentiation operation in etherum

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, private-blockchain, precompiled-contracts

I have Alice who should do some cryptographic operations off-chain. Then a smart contact has to verify equality by performing Modular exponentiation operation. 
I attached an image of the off-chain and on-chain operations. Is there any library that can verify the last equality in the image. I tried to write the math here, but writing math equations is not allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modular exponentiation can be computed on Ethereum using a precompile, which is included in all client implementations since the Byzantium fork (cf [EIP-198](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md)) at address 0x05.
Precompiles can be called from a Solidity smart-contract using assembly code.

I couldn't find a proper smart-contract calling the modular exponentiation precompile but as an example, calling the ecmul (at address 0x07) can be done using the following code:

```
  function ecmul(uint256 x, uint256 y, uint256 scalar) public constant returns(uint256[2] p) {
    // With a public key (x, y), this computes p = scalar * (x, y).
    uint256[3] memory input;
    input[0] = bx;
    input[1] = by;
    input[2] = scalar;
    assembly {
      // call ecmul precompile
      if iszero(call(not(0), 0x07, 0, input, 0x60, p, 0x40)) {
        revert(0, 0)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to test the code in practice, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

From the answer of @Julien Marchand it's possible to create the function viewing the attributes of the precompiled contract:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L226

Address: `0x05` https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L56

The verify function is untested but maybe could help.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract ModularCheck {

    // Untested code
    function verify(uint256 _D, uint256 _C, uint256 _c, uint256 _h, uint256 _z, uint256 _g, uint256 _l, uint256 _modulus) public returns (bool){
        uint256 exp1 = modExp(_C, _c, _modulus);
        uint256 exp2 = modExp(_h, _z, _modulus);
        uint256 exp3 = modExp(_g, _l, _modulus);

        if(_D == mulmod(mulmod(exp1,exp2, _modulus),exp3, _modulus)) return true;

    }

    function modExp(uint256 _b, uint256 _e, uint256 _m) public returns (uint256 result) {
        assembly {
            // Free memory pointer
            let pointer := mload(0x40)

            // Define length of base, exponent and modulus. 0x20 == 32 bytes
            mstore(pointer, 0x20)
            mstore(add(pointer, 0x20), 0x20)
            mstore(add(pointer, 0x40), 0x20)

            // Define variables base, exponent and modulus
            mstore(add(pointer, 0x60), _b)
            mstore(add(pointer, 0x80), _e)
            mstore(add(pointer, 0xa0), _m)

            // Store the result
            let value := mload(0xc0)

            // Call the precompiled contract 0x05 = bigModExp
            if iszero(call(not(0), 0x05, 0, pointer, 0xc0, value, 0x20)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }

            result := mload(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @albeerto, can I test this code on remix. or should I have account on etherum blockchain to call the contract at 0x05

Comment: You can test the contract on remix.

Comment: But remix has the precompiled contract 0x05 ? in other words, on the current time, I do not have access to the real etherum blockchain so can I test it locally on remix

Comment: Yes, it has, you only need to copy the code and paste on remix. If you prefer, copy only the function modExp()  to your contract.

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I create values to test your answer. In other words, How to generate values for D,C,c,l,z to test your contract.

Comment: These values are generated offchain (as you say, and I don't know how to generate them), thus the `verify` function is untested. I only wrote the verify function to show how to use `modExp()` for your particular case. `modExp()` function can be tested passing the base, exponent and modulus as attributes of the function.