# After EIP 198 introduction, how much gas is required for RSA signature verification in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, evm, eip

Thanks to the introduction of EIP 198, RSA signature verification is now feasible in Ethereum.

How much gas is required for such a verification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about it here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md

> A 4096-bit RSA exponentiation would cost `mult_complexity(512) * 4095 / 100 = 22853376` gas in the worst case, though RSA verification in
>   practice usually uses an exponent of 3 or 65537, which would reduce
>   the gas consumption to `5580` or`89292`, respectively.

---

According with the first example of the EIP, the function `modExp()` implemented [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71590/7453) and the inputs:

```
0x03
0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2e
0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
```

the execution cost was `14248` gas.