# Validating RSA, Ed25519 and ECDSA signatures in solidity

Tags: solidity, cryptography

I am writing a contract in solidity for verifying multiple signature schemes.I found that solidity supports ECDSA, but how do I add check for RSA and Ed25519. is there any existing method/library developed that can be used?

Answer (score 3):

RSA signature verification is possible in ethereum by virtue of [EIP-198](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md). You can see an example usage in modExp function in this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71590/53608). There is a draft [EIP-665](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-665.md) for Ed25519 signature verification. This is not final yet.