# How do I implement RSA in solidity for large numbers?

Tags: math

I want to implement RSA in solidity, but for large values, it gives back an overflow error and it does not work correctly. How do I fix it?

Comment: Solidity only supports 256 bits arithmetic. To support RSA it will require implementing your own arithmetic operations for larger numbers. Using the bigModExp precompile could be helpful https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71590.