# How Do I use Precompiled contract in solidity?

Tags: precompiled-contracts

I want to utilize a precompiled contract (EIP-196) in my smart contract. First of all, I don't know how to call this precompiled contract in my contract. Secondly, I have found a code in bellow links that uses this method. However, I want to do an addition on the elliptic curve, which has two points (x,y), while it returns back a point.

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13003

Comment: Check this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71565/verifying-modular-exponentiation-operation-in-etherum. It uses eccMul precompiled contract 0x7. You'll have to do something similar for eccAdd 0x6.